# panic: interface conversion: interface {} is **string, not string

Tags: string, pointers, go, interface

How to convert double pointer string to string?

In this example we can directly pass string argument. But I have double pointer string to string requirement in my app.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := "ss"
    a := &s
    Modify(&a)
}

func Modify(s interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(s)

}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/d4hrG9LzLNO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You require to assert `**string` to get underlying value wrapped around `interface{}`. And then dereference the value of string using `double` pointer.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := "ss"
    a := &s
    Modify(&a)
}

func Modify(s interface{}) {
     fmt.Println(**s.(**string))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/c8NZeu_90fg)

Comment: how i can do this if i dont know what is the type of variable `s` on `Modify` method ?
I'am stuck about 4 hours ago until now,,

Answer (score 5):

If you can't avoid having a `**string`, this is how you can handle it: assert `**string` from the `interface{}` value (since this is what it contains), and then dereference the pointer which gives you `*string` which you again can dereference which gives you the `string` value.

```
func main() {
    s := "ss"
    a := &s

    fmt.Println("Before a:", *a)
    Modify(&a)
    fmt.Println("After a:", *a)
    fmt.Println("After s:", s)
}

func Modify(s interface{}) {
    sp := s.(**string)
    **sp = "modified"
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8Lx10aOjxUY)):

```
Before a: ss
After a: modified
After s: modified
```

But know that if you already have a variable of `*string` type (which is `a`), you don't need to take and pass its address, you can pass it as-is (a `*string` value):

```
func main() {
    s := "ss"
    a := &s

    fmt.Println("Before a:", *a)
    Modify(a)
    fmt.Println("After a:", *a)
    fmt.Println("After s:", s)
}

func Modify(s interface{}) {
    sp := s.(*string)
    *sp = "modified"
}
```

Output again will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/PlZTKh6Rsnq)):

```
Before a: ss
After a: modified
After s: modified
```

**Note** that in both cases the value pointed by `a` changed to `"modified"`, but the value of `s` also changed. This is because inside `Modify()` we modified the *pointed-pointed* value. If you only want `a` to change (more specifically the value pointed by `a`) but you don't want to change `s`, then inside `Modify()` you should only modify the value pointed by `sp`, which will be the variable `a`, but not the pointed-pointed value (which is `s`). In order to only change the pointed value, you have to assign a value of type `*string` to it:

```
func main() {
    s := "ss"
    a := &s

    fmt.Println("Before a:", *a)
    Modify(&a)
    fmt.Println("After a:", *a)
    fmt.Println("After s:", s)
}

func Modify(s interface{}) {
    sp := s.(**string)
    newValue := "modified"
    *sp = &newValue
}
```

This time the output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5IVxY3MHlk9)):

```
Before a: ss
After a: modified
After s: ss
```

As you can see, `Modify()` modified the value pointed by `a`, but `s` remained unchanged.